# Jade - Can I reference DOM element in 'if' statement?

Tags: pug

I have the following simple `index.jade`:

```
input#elem1
'then I need the following:'
if #elem1.val()='A' then
    label#elem2 input=A
```

I know I can do this in my js file, but I was looking for a simpler solution using Jade only.

Comment: point taken. edited accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no way to do this w\o JS.
Here is the closest solution - 
[from ForbesLindesay](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1960#issuecomment-105456079)

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid this isn't possible in Jade. Jade is a templating language, it produces the HTML *before* rendering. Whatever if/else logic that you put in Jade only determines whether something will be *rendered* or not.

In another sense, it's not dynamic. Your `if #elem1.val()='A'` would have no meaning because at the time of converting Jade to HTML, `#elem1` wouldn't have a value. And by the time it's rendered so it could have value, it's too late for Jade to do anything about it. It's fundamentally not possible.

I hope that makes sense. You might wanna look into what a templating language actually is: [What is a templating language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026597/what-is-a-templating-language)